# javascript_include_tag include all Files from specific folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, url

When I want to include all JavaScript files from the folder `js` with the following code the url looks like `javascripts/public/javascripts/js/...`.

`<%= javascript_include_tag *Dir["public/javascripts/js/**/*.js"] %>`

When I change the code to `<%= javascript_include_tag *Dir["js/**/*.js"] %>` the url looks like `js/...`?

How do I have to change my code so that the url is `javascripts/js/...`?

Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails version 3.1 and above then you can put your all js files inside a folder like `app/assets/javascript/my_folder` and make one js manifest file and put `//= require_tree .` line inside that file. Now open `config/application.rb` file and add this line.
`config.assets.precompile += %w( my_folder/manifest_file_name.js)`